# matrix in GitHub Actions: how to use a json defined in env variable as matrix list

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a list of service which I want to pull, and for that i wanted to use matrix. Since this list of services defined in `SERVCES_JSON` env variable will also be used in other jobs, I would like to reused in to convert to list, instead of defining the same list again.

```yaml
name: Deployment
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  SERVICES_JSON: '[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]'

jobs:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  name: Pull docker images
  strategy:
    matrix:
      service: ${{ fromJson($SERVICES_JSON) }}
    steps:
      - name: Prepare new image name
        env:
          SERVICE: ${{ matrix.service }}
        run: echo "NEW_IMAGE=${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${PROJECT}/${SERVICE}:${BUILD}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

The snippet I gave - `service: ${{ fromJson($SERVICES_JSON) }}` - it's not correct, but it's somthing similiar that I want to have there.

Comment: It doesn't recognize `SERVICES_JSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the `env` context in `matrix`. You can use a job with outputs to set the matrix:

```yaml
env:
  SERVICES_JSON: |
    [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ]

jobs:
  gen-matrix:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Generate Matrix
        id: gen-matrix
        run: |
          # use heredoc with random delimiter for multiline JSON
          delimiter="$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 20)"
          echo "services<<$delimiter
          $SERVICES_JSON
          $delimiter" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    outputs:
      services: ${{ steps.gen-matrix.outputs.services }}
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: gen-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix:
        service: ${{ fromJson(needs.gen-matrix.outputs.services) }}
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ matrix.service }}
```

Comment: The syntax to set multiline output doesn't look right. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-a-multiline-string. Either append each line to `GITHUB_OUTPUT` or enclose the complete it in curly braces as mentioned in the docs. Also, no need to set it as a multline output at all. It can simply be compacted to one line using `jq` e.g. `echo "SERVICES_JOSN=$(jq -c <<< '${{ env.SERVICES_JSON }})' >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`.

Comment: @Azeem "The syntax to set multiline output doesn't look right." They just appear different but are actually the same. Using a random delimiter is safer as it avoids potential conflict with the contents. "It can simply be compacted to one line using `jq`" Yes you are correct. But multiline output is more general and can be used in other situations, not only JSON. I just copied it from my setup that is not using JSON.

Comment: Got it. It was the starting and closing quotes that I missed. That's why it's the same. I suggested `jq` as the given multiline value was JSON. You might want to add links to the relevant docs to make it more detailed e.g. how to set an output and the context availability.